# How do I build a Hashmap in a superclass which can be given local values in a class and used in a separate classes main method?

Tags: java, for-loop, inheritance, hashmap

Everyone is focusing on the specific example code I Poorly submitted so I'm just removing that.

Focusing more on the concepts and with the disclaimer that I very much understand this is a newbie question:

I have a superclass we'll call SuperA. I have multiple subclasses of SuperA we'll call SubA, SubB, SubC... assume this carries on essentially forever.

Each subclass holds (among other things) a hashmap with key,value pairs which are different from each other subclass, but all subclasses have this hashmap.

What I can already do: I have a method that can get SubA.hashmap and do stuff with it. I can change this for SubB, SubC, etc. It works just fine.

What I want to do: I want to put all the subclasses in an array and do stuff with each subclass.hashmap in a generic way so that it can be done in a loop.

What is stopping me from doing what I want to do: In order for all the subclasses to be in the array and for a loop to interact with each, I need them all to be referenced at the superclass level (SuperA[]). With all of my current attempts to figure this out, for( sub : SuperA[]){ sub.hashmap } either has null pointer (due to SuperA not having instantiated hashmap) or the value of SuperA.hashmap instead of SubA.hashmap (or SubB.hashmap).

The question: How can I build the superclass > subclass.hashmap relationship in such a way where I can have a collection of subclasses and, in a separate class and method, iterate over that collection with access to each subclass.hashmap?

Comment: Everything here is confusing. Serious hints: **static** and super/subclassing do **not** go together well. Sorry, but your approach is awfully wrong. Start by reading about static vs. non-static; then drop all those static keywords; and maybe replace them with the protected keyword. And read about what that means.

Comment: Isn't super a keyword? Could you really use it as a variable name (in or loop) ?

Comment: @dev8080 yes it's a keyword, this isn't the code I'm actually using. I just put super there so it would be more obvious what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. In other method I constructed a

```
 HashMap<SuperA,HashMap<String,ObjectA>> masterMap = new...
```

then did

```
for(SuperA sub: masterMap.keySet()){
  for (DataA dataObj : masterMap.get(sub).values()){
    stuff
  }
}
```

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that you need to decide between `static` and Inheritance i.e., they don't work together in Object Oriented World. In simple words, you can't inherit the `static` members of a class.

Comment: I was looking in that direction already, but I guess I'm not quite good enough at OOP to fully understand what I'm looking at. My current misunderstanding is how can I create something like these hMaps so that they CAN be accessed by an external class like AppMain? I can remove the inheritance from SuperA so hMap becomes an extension, but that doesn't seem to fix the static issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

It's `null` because you never initialize your `hMap`. You need to write `hMap = new HashMap<>();` in your `SuperA` to make it work.

Comment: This fixes a nullPointer exception, but it means that all super.hMap point to SuperA.hMap instead of pointing to B.hMap and then C.hMap which is what I'm trying to do.